# Laravel 4 and Eloquent, hasMany relation seems not work

Tags: mysql, select, join, laravel-4, eloquent

I've 2 models

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_data() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product_translate','id_product');
    }

}
```

and

```
class Product_translate extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'product_translates';

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product','id_product');
    }

}
```

in my controller, if i try use Eloquent:

```
class PublicController extends BaseController {

    public function home() 
    {
        $products = Product::find(1)->product_data;

        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        $last_query = end($queries);

        echo "<pre>";

        print_r($last_query);
        print_r($products);

        echo "</pre>";
    }

}
```

This is what I obtain:

```
Array
(
    [query] => select * from `tp450products` where `id` = ? limit 1
    [bindings] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [time] => 0.88
)
```

No results as you can see, only the query (run correctly in phpmyadmin),

But if i try to use change using only find(1):

```
class PublicController extends BaseController {

        public function home() 
        {
            $products = Product::find(1);

            $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
            $last_query = end($queries);

            echo "<pre>";

            print_r($last_query);
            print_r($products);

            echo "</pre>";
        }

    }
```

I obtain the record of table "products", but I want to get the join with "product_translates".
No idea what is going wrong!

The db is correctly linked and the "product_translates" has the right foreign key

Here the 2 tables (only a record of each):

```
Products
id | type | best | featured | voto | created_at          | updated_at
1  | 1    | 0    | 0        | 0    | 2014-03-19 00:00:00 | 2014-03-12 13:26:23

Product_translates
id | id_product | id_lang | nome              | slug
1  | 1          | 1       | mutande ascellari | mutande-ascellari
```

**EDIT 1**

No problem using query builder, but why with Eloquent ORM i've that problem?

class PublicController extends BaseController {

```
public function home() 
{
    $products = DB::table('products')->leftJoin('product_translates','product_translates.id_product','=','products.id')->get();

    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    $last_query = end($queries);

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($last_query);
    print_r($products);

    echo "</pre>";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this and let's see what you get:

```
class PublicController extends BaseController {

    public function home() 
    {
        $product = Product::find(1);
        $p1 = Product::with('product_data')->where('id',1)->get();

        echo "<pre>";

        echo '---- Product';
        var_dump($product);

        echo '---- Product data values';
        var_dump($product->product_data);

        echo '---- Product data query';
        var_dump($product->product_data());

        echo '---- Product data eager loaded';
        var_dump($p1);

        echo "</pre>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, my fault I've copy the wrong string from my code, the method i'm using di product_data indeed. Question updated

Comment: errr nope... this give a huuuge amount of data, not sure what i'm seeing... thanks anyway, i think the problem is correlate with the name of the method, i'm doing some experiments

Comment: Could you pastebin this data? I just put some headers to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Some data is missing, the '---- Product data eager loaded' didn't came.

Answer (score 0):

this problem kill me for long time.. this is a true solution

you model name for Product_translate should be ProductTranslate and then you not need to set table name property... naming is so important in eloquent in specified class name and (multi name part).. the solution below:

```
//file models/Product.php
class Product extends Eloquent 

    // in this name glass you well get $product->product_translates property 
    // gift  from eloquent dynamic property!!
    public function productTranslates() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductTranslate');
    }
}

//file models/Product.php
class ProductTranslate extends Eloquent {

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }
}


// this will be work now!!
class PublicController extends BaseController {

    public function home() 
    {
        $products = Product::find(1);

        foreach($products->product_translates as $product_translate)
             echo $product_translate->name . " <br> ";

        $translates = ProductTranslate::All();

        foreach($translates as $translate)
             echo $translate->name. ": ". $translate->product->price . " <br> ";
    }

}
```